# Hibernate HQL update with where in

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I would like to update status by using a list collection in "where in" clause.
The parameter "UserId" is a list of an object UserId which contains two attributs like creationDate and ref.

Example :

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.status = ?2 where u.userid ?1")
void updateAllUserStatus( List<UserId> usersId, UserStatus status);



public class UserId implements Serializable {

    @Type(type="date")
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;
    
    @Type(type = "string")
    @Column(name = "user_ref")
    private String ref;
}
```

Is update query by using a collection with object possible ?
Or i should update one by one ?

I tried with parameter List **usersId** (has two attributs : creation_date and user_ref) which present as below :

Printed out usersId :

> [creation_date: Mon Feb 24 00:00:00 CET 2020 | user_ref :
> testabc-1234-1234-1234-abcdefghigk1, creation_date: Mon Feb 24
> 00:00:00 CET 2020 | user_ref : testabc-1234-1234-1234-abcdefghigk2]

I got this error when i update with condition where userid in

> Parameter value element [creation_date: Mon Feb 24 00:00:00 CET 2020 |
> user_ref : testabc-1234-1234-1234-abcdefghigk1] did not match expected
> type [UserId (n/a)]; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element
> [creation_date: Mon Feb 24 00:00:00 CET 2020 | user_ref :
> testabc-1234-1234-1234-abcdefghigk1] did not match expected type
> [UserId (n/a)]

I did debuging to verify if the the list correctly filled in and it was ok.

Comment: I can't even figure out what the raw SQL update would be here.  Maybe you should show us what SQL you want, and then we can back out and see if Hibernate/JPA can maybe handle it.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : I updated my answer with more precise.

Comment: @Katy What database do you use ?

Comment: I use postgresql.

Comment: I found my problem, it is because i use tapestry and when i pass an object as context it convert to String. This is why i had this error.

Answer (score 2):

That's totally possible, given that your database supports the row value constructor syntax and will create a SQL query similar to this:

```
update User u set u.status = ? where (u.ref, u.creationDate) in ((?,?),(?,?))
```

Comment: By using this hql i have the error. I updated my question with more details.

Comment: Use a query like this: `update User u set u.status = ?2 where u.userid in ?1`

Answer (score 0):

As Christian Beikov noticed, it is possible. I would add the following quotation from the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate):

> `IN` predicates performs a check that a particular value is in a list of values. Its syntax is:
>
> ```
> in_expression ::= single_valued_expression [NOT] IN single_valued_list
> single_valued_list ::= constructor_expression | (subquery) | collection_valued_input_parameter
> constructor_expression ::= (expression[, expression]*)
> ```
>
> The types of the `single_valued_expression` and the individual values in the `single_valued_list` must be consistent.
>
> *JPQL limits the valid types here to string, numeric, date, time, timestamp, and enum types*, and, in JPQL, `single_valued_expression` can only refer to:
>
> - "state fields", which is its term for simple attributes. *Specifically, this excludes association and component/embedded attributes.*
> - entity type expressions.
>
> *In HQL, `single_valued_expression` can refer to a far more broad set of expression types. Single-valued association are allowed, and so are component/embedded attributes, although that feature depends on the level of support for tuple or [row value constructor syntax](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-tuple.html) in the underlying database. Additionally, HQL does not limit the value type in any way, though application developers should be aware that different types may incur limited support based on the underlying database vendor.* This is largely the reason for the JPQL limitations.

So, the usage of this feature will tie you to the particular jpa implementation and database.